# UISwitch not responds to actions if added programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

Cannot fix this problem. Have this funcs:

```
func addSwitch(){
    switchB.setOn(true, animated: false)
    switchB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChange), for:UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    view.addSubview(switchB)
    switchB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    switchB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    switchB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
}
@objc func valueChange(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    if mySwitch.isOn{
        switchB.onTintColor = UIColor.black
    }
    else{
        switchB.onTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

And then i just add it in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSwitch()

    }
```

I see the button but it does not respond to actions.

UPD:

```
class Main: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let switchB = UISwitch()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSwitch()
    }
```

Everything works in new project but in current - no.
Im using google maps , maybe problem in maps layer, but i see my button.

UPD2 : WORKS! (Thanks Francesco Deliro) The google mapView settings property has a property called consumesGestureInView that is set to true by default try with: `yourMapView.settings.consumesGestureInView = false`

Comment: If you place a `print()` statement just within the `valueChange(mySwitch:)` do you not get any result?

Comment: i tried your code it working fine!! i just add var switchB = UISwitch()

Comment: Your code works fine. can you please add code how you define `switchB`.

Comment: UPD my question, how i define my UISwitch

Comment: How would _widthAnchor_ and _heightAnchor_ be of switch would be 50 ?

Comment: Sateesh  i removed it, it works fine without this anchors

Comment: @George_E i havent a result, button is dead)

Comment: Im using google maps , maybe problem in maps layer, but i see my button

Comment: The google mapView settings property has a property called consumesGestureInView that is set to true by default try with: `yourMapView.settings.consumesGestureInView = false`

Comment: @Francesco Deliro thanks!!!

Comment: @ZhaZha You’re welcome ;)

Answer (score -1):

There is no issue with your code. Tint color action is working preperly. make sure the switchbB variable is prroper.

```
var switchbB = UISwitch()

    func addSwitch(){
            switchbB.setOn(true, animated: false)
            switchbB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChange), for:UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
            view.addSubview(switchbB)
            switchbB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            switchbB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            switchbB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        }

  @objc func valueChange(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
            if mySwitch.isOn{
                switchbB.onTintColor = UIColor.black
            }
            else{
                switchbB.onTintColor = UIColor.white
            }
        }
```

Comment: the variable is shown as being 'proper', the issue was due to size constraints and being embedded in a google map